# On $\mathbf{a}'(t) \times \mathbf{a}(t) = \mathbf{0}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

In vector analysis, a vector-valued function $\mathbf{a}(t)$ doesn't change its direction iff $\mathbf{a}'(t) \times \mathbf{a}(t) = \mathbf{0}$ holds.

When I try to prove this, I use an extra assumption that $\mathbf{a}(t)$ vanishes nowhere. I wonder if it is necessary for a proof.

Here is my approach.

Suppose $\mathbf{a}'(t)\times\mathbf{a}(t)=\mathbf{0}$, then $\mathbf{e}(t) = \dfrac{{\mathbf{a}(t)}}{{|\mathbf{a}(t)|}}=\dfrac{{\mathbf{a}(t)}}{{f(t)}}$ is unit vector, **where $f(t)=|\mathbf{a}(t)|$ vanishes nowhere**. Only need to show $\mathbf{e}(t)$ is constant. Since $\mathbf{e}'(t)\cdot \mathbf{e}(t)=0$, $\mathbf{e}'(t)\cdot \mathbf{a}(t)=0$. It follows
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{a}(t)&=&f(t)\mathbf{e}(t),\\
\mathbf{a}'(t)&=&f'(t)\mathbf{e}(t)+f(t)\mathbf{e}'(t),\\
\mathbf{a}'(t)\times\mathbf{a}(t)&=&f(t)\mathbf{e}'(t)\times\mathbf{a}(t)=\mathbf{0},
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore $\mathbf{e}'(t)\times\mathbf{a}(t)=\mathbf{0}$. Set $\mathbf{e}'(t)=\lambda(t)\mathbf{a}(t)$,
$$\mathbf{e}'(t)\cdot \mathbf{a}(t)=\lambda(t)\mathbf{a}(t)\cdot \mathbf{a}(t)=\lambda(t)f^2(t)=0,$$
It follows that $\lambda(t)=0$, $\mathbf{e}'(t)=0$, $\mathbf{e}(t)$ is constant.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the direction of $\mathbf a(t)$ when it vanishes?

Comment: It's not necessary. For example, $\mathbf{a}(t)=t\mathbf{i}$ vanishes at $t=0$.

Comment: @corvus Hmm... Maybe I should prove $\mathbf{a}(t)=f(t)\mathbf{e}$ for some fixed unit vector $\mathbf{e}$.

Comment: @corvus There is a gap in my proof. I don't know whether $\mathbf{a}(t)$ can be expressed as a multiple of a fixed unit vector, and I need to take $|\mathbf{a}(t)|$ as denominator.

Comment: I don't see your proof. Edit your question to make it clear and concrete to get clear and concrete answers.

Comment: @corvus I've written my approach. Please help me check it. Thanks.

Comment: How do you set $\mathbf{e}'(t)=\lambda(t)\mathbf{a}(t)$?

Comment: You actually doesn't need so much words to prove your statement. Cross product is zero when either vector is zero, or when they are proportional. It follows directly from the definition.

Comment: @corvus But I don't know how to derive its direction unchanged.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45665/discussion-between-gzd15-and-corvus).